# Small relay with no coil (or reversed) polarity

Tags: relay

Due to a wrong design I'm searching for a relay with the same footprint of the AGN THT family:

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/315/mech_eng_gn-1075921.pdf

but with no coil polarity or, at least, with a reversed one.
It seems all the relays as small as this have the coil polarized.

Is there a reason for this or I just did a wrong search?

Comment: well, you can save a significant of space when you make the switch a magnet, not just a piece of ferromagnetic material. But then, of course, polarity matters.

Comment: Hence, if I understand correctly, in order to make such a small relay, they all use a magnet. So it's hard to find a replacement without the polarity...